# Obtaining the target ids of dynamic text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button which adds dynamic columns on clicking that. I tried to get the target id of each column.

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
    <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
</div>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        alert("target id" + e.target.id); // I get nothing here
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

How to get target ids and also if it has some value I want to print that as well before removing the column for dynamic column added ?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var max_fields = 10,
    wrapper = $('.input_fields_wrap'),
    add_button = $('.add_field_button'),
    x = 1;

$(add_button).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) {
        x++;
        $(wrapper).append('<div><input id="' + x + '" type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>');
    }
});

$(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_field', function(e) {
    var div = $(this).parent('div'),
        input = div.find('input');
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log('target id:', input.attr('id'));
    console.log('target value:', input.val());

    div.remove();
    x--;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
    <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't giving IDs to the columns !

```
<div>
    <input type="text" name="mytext[]"/>
    <a href="#"class="remove_field"> Remove </a>
</div>
```

I used the x of your code, `var x = 1; //initlal text box count`

```
$(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field" id='+x+'>Remove</a></div>');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7yn7apte/4/

Comment: It works. Just a small doubt will this work even inside the textbox when I try it on click of text field ?